# 3rd Party Bluetooth Keyboard Won't Connect on Sleep Login

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, display, sleep-wake, bluetooth

I've been using my MacBook Pro with 2x cinema displays and like to keep the MBP closed while doing so.

I recently got a bluetooth keyboard but when the OS sleeps and requires a password to log back in, the keyboard won't connect (after sleeping itself).

There's no issue if the keyboard is asleep when the screen isn't locked, it will auto-connect with the stroke of any button.

It's a bit annoying to open up the laptop to log back in and have all the screens reset, is there any way to fix this?

I suppose I could remove the login, but sometimes I want the security - especially when not at home.

Thanks

Comment: *It's a bit annoying to open up the laptop to log back in and have all the screens reset...*  I'm not understanding how this relates.  Can't you wake your BT keyboard from sleep with the press of a button?  It should automatically connect to the device it was last connected to.  What make keyboard? What version of macOS?

Comment: It's a JETech, with an Apple style. It should reconnect on the press of a button - sometimes it does, but half the time it won't (despite pressing multiple buttons and switching off and on). In these cases I need to open the laptop to log in, disconnect the keyboard then pair them again. I was doing this a minimum of once a day, sometimes multiple times - but, as I said, sometimes it would work fine.